# Batch file : Recursive loop

Tags: batch-file

I am trying a simple operation in a batch file. Iterate through tokens and perform some task for each token.

Can someone point out why following script results in a recursive loop and iterating through the first token all the time ?

```
@echo off
set servers=10.20.30.40,200.300.400.500
echo %servers%
Call :configureDataStore "%servers%"
goto :eos
:configureDataStore
set list=%servers%
set list=%list:"=%
FOR /f "tokens=1* delims=," %%a IN ("%list%") DO (
  if not "%%a" == "" call :configureSlave %%a  
  if not "%%b" == "" (
     set servers = %%b
     call :configureDataStore "%%b"
  )
)
goto :eos
:configureSlave
   echo In subroutine %1
   goto :eos

:eos
```

Comment: Can you please explain more, what do you mean "iterating through the first token all the time" it would iterate for both the first and second token.

Comment: The output on console is "In subroutine 10.20.30.40" ... until you finally get max recursion exceeded error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a very simple logic error. You call `:configureDataStore` with one parameter, but inside the routine you reference `%servers%` (a constant) when you should be using `%1` (the parameter)

Actually, you should use `%~1` if you want to remove the enclosing quotes.

Instead of using `goto :eos`, you should use `goto :eof`. There is always an implicit `:eof` label at the end of every script, so you don't have to physically put `:eof` at the end of the file.

A more modern version that I prefer is `exit /b`, which does the exact same thing as `goto :eof`. The advantage of `exit /b` is it allows you to set the ERRORLEVEL if you want: `exit /b 1`.

Rather than using a generic word like "subroutine", you can use `%0` to get the name of the currently executing subroutine. You can use `%*` to get all passed parameters (no difference from `%1` in this case)

As currently written, you are using way more variables than are needed. But this is obviously unfinished code, and I don't know where you are going with it. So I left the variable usage unchanged.

```
@echo off
set servers=10.20.30.40,200.300.400.500
echo %servers%
Call :configureDataStore "%servers%"
exit /b

:configureDataStore
set "list=%~1"
FOR /f "tokens=1* delims=," %%a IN ("%list%") DO (
  if not "%%a" == "" call :configureSlave %%a
  if not "%%b" == "" (
     set servers = %%b
     call :configureDataStore "%%b"
  )
)
exit /b

:configureSlave
echo In %0 %*
exit /b
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not really an experienced batch script writer so yes my code may not look like a finished product. Thanks a lot for your inputs, it will definitely help to improve the code. But, I have a problem, what if I save this script as test.bat and call it from command line.                                                                                 Say, set servers=%1 and now  list=%1 will not work as it will refer to the original arguments.   And Call this script as run test.bat 100,200.

Comment: @MandarKulkarni - No problem there; the value of `%1` is context sensitive. The value reflects the current value on the CALL stack. When you call a subroutine, the subroutine has its own local value of `%1`. When you return to the caller, the caller sees the original value from its command line. Give it a try - experimentation (done safely) is the best way to learn :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in this line, if I understand what you are trying to do (which is mightily over-engineered)

```
 set servers = %%b
```

Remove the spaces like so, as you were creating a variable "%servers %" with the space.

```
 set servers=%%b
```